# Set default values for object array in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

How can we set default values for an array of objects in JSON schema definition?

The following shows the specific section of schema. The default data provided is not helping.

```
 "children": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "fname": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "lname": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "default": [{
    "fname": "x",
    "lname": "ray"
  }]
}
```

I am later converting this schema to java object using **jsonschema2pojo** maven plugin. So I am expecting the same default data to be available in the generated classes. The above mentioned approach works perfectly for sting, number etc.. but not for object array. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the `default` keyword does not provide any validation assertion. It's merely an annotation. With that said, you can add `default` to the schema property definition.  There's no guarantee it will be used in the pojo generation. that's dependent on the  implementation used.

```
"children": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "fname": {
        "type": "string",
        "default": "x"
      },
      "lname": {
        "type": "string",
        "default": "ray",
        "examples": [ "one", "two"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> The examples keyword is a place to provide an array of examples that validate against the schema. This isn’t used for validation, but may help with explaining the effect and purpose of the schema to a reader. Each entry should validate against the schema in which it resides, but that isn’t strictly required. There is no need to duplicate the default value in the examples array, since default will be treated as another example.

Comment: I agree. But the issue is that I may need to add more elements to array in real scenario .. like   "default": [{
    "fname": "x",
    "lname": "ray"
  }, {
    "fname": "gamma",
    "lname": "ray"
  }]

Comment: You can't have multiple values for a default value. But you can use examples

Comment: Updated the answer. Please mark it as accepted if that's what you need

Comment: Thanks!. Unfortunately, that did not served the purpose. I solved it with a different approach of populating the POJOs with values from a yml file.